# Issue with file I/O on android

Tags: android, sd-card, fwrite, rom

I met a problem recently.
I need to write some tmp data to the file(use API fwrite) in /data/data/com.**.**/tmp on Android.

The test program just run on one thread.
and write data several hundred KB one time.

**case 1:**
In this case, I create 2 file in this path first, and then write this 2 tmp files by turns.

The write process would pause few time once in a while , sometime it would few seconds.
and if just write one tmp(but fopen this 2 file) file in this case, it is the same situation.

**case 2:**
If there just one tmp file exist in this directory. 
the write process would never pause..

Why the write process would pause continuously in case 1 ?

Thank for your help.

Update:

I have tested several versions of Android including 2.3.7 , 4.0.3, 4.1

The code is:

```
FILE *tmp1 = fopen(tmp1,"wb"); 
FILE *tmp2 = fopen(tmp2,"wb"); 
FILE *swap = tmp1; 

while(..) { 
    if (..) 
        swap = tmp2; 
    else
        swap = tmp1;

    fwrite(.., swap)
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?  What version of Android are you using?

Comment: I even call fclose() after every fwrite() but it is the same situation in case 1 and after some test, I guess the situation would never change as long as more than 2 file exist in one directory.  

is my view false? why?